# How to add 5px border around Videoview?

Tags: android, padding, android-xml, android-videoview, android-background

I have the following videoview:

```
 <VideoView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="316dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsvideo" />
```

It works fine, however I want a thin black line around it. I tried setting the padding attribute to 5px and setting the background to a color like this:

```
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@color/black"
```

but that just made the entire videoview black and prevented the video from displaying, how do I add a boundary to the videoview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the margin you can setup the tag **`android:layout_margin="5dp"`** in the `VideoView` itself. The result would look like this:

[image]

The XML code for the `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="316dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

about the black background, I think the best way would be to use a frame around the VideoView, I agree with @Mariano Di Stefano there (at least it is simple)

Comment: @Roymunson have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as the correct one, let me know if this helped =)

Answer (score 0):

You could put VieoView inside some other (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or even FrameLayout) and set margin & black background to this parent (and of course center your VideoView in both directions).